# how to convert time format from number to string?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i fetched from created field date and time like this format `2011-3-10 17:26:50` and i want to convert to this format `March 13, 2010` how can i do this with php or cakephp 1.3

```
     <?php

  $i = 0;
foreach($articles as $$article ):

                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $article['Article']['title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $article['Article']['created'];;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean "fetched" as in retrieving from MySQL. The simplest/quickest (but also the most like to blow up and kick your dog) is to simply do

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date_from_database);
$formatted = date('F j, Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: And if you don't want to kick your dog, use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function `strtotime($string)`, that will take dates/time strings in a variety of formats (including MySQL's datetime format) and convert it to a Unix timestamp integer (number of seconds since **1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC**). You can then use `date('F j, Y', $time)` to convert that integer into whatever string representation you want, using the tokens found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Two additional considerations are localization and timezone awareness. I won't go into the first since it doesn't seem like you need it, but where timezone matters, it can be easier to use PHP's DateTime classes, which you can read about [[here]](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Here's an example:

```
<?php

// for example, if you're storing times in UTC in your DB
$dbTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

// we'll use this for displaying times in the user's timezone.
// for example, my timezone:
$displayTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto');

foreach ($articles as $article):
    // Create a timezone-aware DateTime object from your article's creation date
    $dt = new DateTime($article['Article']['create'], $dbTimezone);
    $dt->setTimezone($displayTimezone);
    echo $dt->format('F j, Y');
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?
I'm guessing your datetime format.  you may need to adjust it.

```
echo date('F d, Y',date_create_from_format('Y-n-d h:i:s','2011-3-10 17:26:50'));
```

[date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve it:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-j H:i:s', $article['Article']['created']);
echo date_format($date, 'F d, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use the Cakephp Time Helper.

```
//Add to appcontroller or articles_controller
var $helpers = array('Time');

//Add this to view file
echo $this->Time->niceShort($article['Article']['created']);
```

Besides `niceShort` there are more options that might fit your needs better. Check CakePHP documentation.

Thanks,